# New SQLAzure databases are not visable in the portal nor via the powershell cmdlets

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-resource-manager

Last week I created 8 databases on a V12 SqlAzure server via powershell and ARM templates, it worked fine. We started to use these databases in SQL Management studio and have set up users and tables etc. There is some data in them and we can select and update as expected. In short they work!

But today I wanted to apply some resource locks to the databases using the azure powershell cmdlet `New-AzureRmResourceLock` but I'm finding that the command `Get-AzureRmResource | Where-Object {$_.ResourceType -eq "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases"}` does not return the databases I'm looking for!

Also I now look in the portal https://portal.azure.com and I see the SQL Servers listed, and when i enter the blade for my sql server I see the databases. But if I click on a DB I'm lead to a not found resource. Also when using the SQL Databases blade I don't see any of the databases listed.

As an aside if I log on to the classic portal https://manage.windowsazure.com I can see the sql server and see all the databases, and click on them and configure them.

I don't really want to have to recreate all these databases as we have started to set them up with schemas, users and data but do need to be able to use the cmdlets to change them especially to add resource locks to them.

Has anyone see this before? and what could i try to bring them back so i can use powershell to configure them again.

Comment: It seems like it's a problem of the resource manager. Have you tried to move your sql server from one resource group to another?

Comment: I agree. I've tried moving resourcegroups, it did move (and the databases) but the same issue is present, sad times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was in touch with Microsoft support last week and they had a look. this is the resolution.

> From: Microsoft support Email
>
> I suspect that our case issue derives from stale subscription cache. 
>   In summary, subscription cache can become stale when changes made
>   within a subscription occur over time.  In an effort to mitigate our
>   case issue, I have refreshed the subscription cache from the backend.

After they had a look it was sorted out that day, both the portal and more importantly the command line are fixed.

Thanks All

Answer (score 0):

Please provide your subscription id, server name and missing database names and I will have this investigated.  Apologies for the inconvenience.  You can send details to me at bill dot gibson at microsoft . com.

Comment: Thanks for the post Bill, but got this sorted last week via the official support channel.